# Is it possible to add partitions to an already existing table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I have a table (`instrument_balance_hist`) with almost a billion rows. I want to partition it by the attribute `instrument_id` which is the type of `NUMBER(6)`, I used the query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE instrument_balance_hist ADD  PARTITION by RANGE( instrument_id ) (
partition p1 VALUE LESS THAN (100),
partition p2 VALUE LESS THAN (200),
partition p3 VALUE LESS THAN (300),
partition p4 VALUE LESS THAN (400),
partition p5 VALUE LESS THAN (500),
partition p6 VALUE LESS THAN (600)
);
```

And the query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE instrument_balance_hist ADD  PARTITION by HASH (instrument_id)(
partition p1,
partition p2,
partition p3,
partition p4 );
```

Both queries return invalid data type at "by". Now I'm not sure if it is even possible to partition an existing table as all the tutorials on youtube do it by making a duplicate table.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Prior to 12.2, you can't partition an existing table.  Starting in 12.2, you can with an `alter table ... modify` https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5

Comment: Does this answer your question https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5

Comment: @JustinCave, not fully correct. Prior 12.2 you can use package [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042). However, it is not a simple one-line command. And it requires double amount of tablespace.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - That isn't really partitioning an existing table.  `dbms_redefinition` is a pretty wrapper on top of a process that creates a partitioned copy of the table, moves the data over, and then does a drop of the old table and rename of the new table.  It's more elegant if you want to reduce the amount of downtime for a table that needs to be editable while you're creating the new table.  But you are fundamentally creating a new table.